# Symfony Process - Background tasks

Tags: php, symfony, proc-open, symfony-process

I would like to run a background process, which is orphaned, with Symfony Process component. I can't use kernel.terminate event. 
This is what I have tried to do:

This is process I would like to run:

```
// script.php
$f = fopen('test'.uniqid().'.txt', 'w');
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    fwrite($f, "Line $i \n");
    sleep(2);
}
fclose ($f);
```

And this is script which I would like to run my process:

```
// test.php
$command = "php script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &";

$p = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process($command);
$p->start();
echo $p->getPid()."\n";
```

The problem is that after `test.php` termination, `script.php` is not working. Termination of main script kills all subprocesses. Is it possible to have orphaned processes running with Symfony Process?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve first before I answer this

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, don't use the Process Component and fall back to php exec:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php

```
exec('php script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

For a more solid solution consider something like a schedule and a crontab executed command to start the process when one needs to be started.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this will do the same thing as the OP is already doing.

Comment: It is not. Process component uses proc_open which actually returns a resource for the output which is monitored by the Process component. exec works different it's fire and forget (given the last `&` at the end of the executed command)

Comment: Process lib is bloated and useless. Lost a lot of time playing with it and ended up with old good exec().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `at` (`atd`) or `cron` with a custom queue. PHP invokes synchronous command which enqueues the desired command for later execution. The `at` is quite powerful and standard component of unix systems. You simply run `at now + 10 min` and push commands to its stdin, then the `atd` daemon will run your commands in 10 minutes.

If you wish to run your command directly from PHP, try to add shell: `new Process('/bin/sh -c "php script.php &"')`. I'm not sure how exactly Process class invokes the command, but if & does not work, one more shell in between will do the trick (that is what `exec()` does).